# How do I open an accordion with an external link or anchor on the same page?

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I need to be able to create from an external page or within it an anchor that opens the accordion. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#accordion li.active").addClass("open").children("ul").show();
      $("#accordion li.has-sub>a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).removeAttr("href");
        var element = $(this).parent("li");
        if (element.hasClass("open")) {
          element.removeClass("open");
          element.find("li").removeClass("open");
          element.find("ul").slideUp(200);
        } else {
          element.addClass("open");
          element.children("ul").slideDown(200);
          element.siblings("li").children("ul").slideUp(200);
          element.siblings("li").removeClass("open");
          element.siblings("li").find("li").removeClass("open");
          element.siblings("li").find("ul").slideUp(200);
        }
      });

    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>

<div id="accordion">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">15:00</a>
      <ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">15:00</a>
      <ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">17:00</a>
      <ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">19:00</a>
      <ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I would also like to be able to insert in each accordion a youtube iframame that blocks when I go on a new accordion. thank you very much